# Enumerate all classes implementing an interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Hello fellow Typescripters!

Here's what I want to do: I want to create an interface -- let's say *IShape* -- and have a bunch of classes (*Rectangle*, *Circle*, *Triangle*) that implement *IShape*.

Let's assume *IShape* has a method called *GetName* that returns a string which consists of the name of the shape. For the sake of this discussion, let's assume that each class implementing *GetName* returns a hard-coded string (e.g.: "Rectangle", "Round thing", "Pointy thing"). Let's also pretend than *IShape* also implements the *Draw* method.

At run time, I would like to be able to list and initialize all the classes that implement *IShape* so that I could show a drop-down of what "shape" the user can select from. When user selects the shape type, the system calls the *Draw* method for that shape.

But here's the kicker: later, I want to be able to create a new classes that implements *IShape* (let's say *Square*, and *Oval*). Next type I run the code, I want the new classes to appear in my drop down without having to change (too much of) the rest of the code.

How would one do this in Typescript?

My goal is to create something that allows other team members to extend my code by adding new "shapes" that implement my interface without having to have a hard-coded list of shapes to accept.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll explain how I would go about doing this in my own code, with the disclaimer that it is somewhat opinionated and you may not find it to your liking.

First off, I'm using standard ES6 `import` and `export`. I would have my shapes all live together in the same folder in my codebase living alongside an `index.ts` file that provides exports from the directory as a whole. Thus my structure might look something like:

```
|-- src/
|    |-- shapes/
|    |    |-- index.ts
|    |    |-- IShape.ts
|    |    |-- Rectangle.ts
|    |    |-- Circle.ts
|    |    |-- Triangle.ts
|    |
|    |-- ShapeList.ts
```

`IShape.ts` looks something like:

```
export interface IShape {
  draw(): void;
}
```

In `Rectangle.ts`, `Circle.ts`, `Triangle.ts` I have code that looks like:

```
import { IShape } from './IShape';

export class Circle implements IShape {
  static getName: () => 'Circle';
  draw(): void {
    //...
  }
}
```

Then in `index.ts` I do:

```
import { Circle } from './Circle';
import { Rectangle } from './Rectangle';
import { Triangle } from './Triangle';

export default [
  Circle,
  Rectangle,
  Triangle,
];
```

Then finally in `ShapeList.ts` I just make use of the shape of the export to get my ShapeList.

import shapes from './shapes';

```
export class ShapeList {
  getItems() {
    return shapes.map(shape => ({
      label: shape.getName(),
      action: () => new shape(), // Setting up a simple factory method for use when this item is selected in the list
    }));
  }

  // ... Rest of the class
}
```

And that's it. Some may argue that this still is hardcoding, since there is an explicit list defined for the shapes, but I would argue otherwise, saying that we are not hardcoding a "ShapesForSpecificReasonList" array, but instead we are taking organic advantage of how we have structured our shapes.

Now adding a new shape is the same as adding a shape otherwise would be:

1. Write the shape class code
2. Make sure it's exported properly